# User creation in admin db vs other DB's in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the difference between the following 2 statements

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser( 
...   { 
...     user: "user1", 
...     pwd: "1234", 
...     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" } ] 
...   } 
... ) 
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "user1",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.createUser( 
...   { 
...     user: "user2", 
...     pwd: "1234", 
...     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" } ] 
...   } 
... ) 
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "user2",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

- 1st case I am creating a user inside "admin" db for the "test" db
  with "readWrite" role
- 2nd case I am creating a user inside "test" db
  for the "test" db itself with "readWrite" role

Are both the same or user created inside admin has more power in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A user account in mongodb is identified by both the database and username.

`admin.testuser` and `test.testuser` are 2 different accounts that can have different passwords and different assigned roles.

When connecting to mongodb the authentication database provided on the command line or in the connection string must match the database where the user was created.

User accounts that are created in a database other than `admin` are limited to roles and permissions in that database.

Considering the two accounts you mention, you would be able to assign the `readWriteAnyDatabase` role to the `admin.test` user, but not the `test.test` user.